# column res_company.write_uid_id does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, odoo-10

while trying to make a link btween Django and Odoo, I used `python manage.py inspectdb > sc_drive/models.py`, but while trying to acces the table using django admin page i get the error below:

> column res_company.write_uid_id does not exist
>
> column res_company.create_uid_id does not exist

**models.py**

```
class ResCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=1)
    # partner = models.ForeignKey('ResPartner', models.DO_NOTHING)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    write_uid = models.ForeignKey('ResUsers', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='user_b_write_uid', blank=True, null=True)
    account_no = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    create_uid = models.ForeignKey('ResUsers', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='user_b_create_uid', blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    write_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    company_registry = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
```

**Ps**: I have already migrated after modifying `related_name=...` on models.py

**admin.py**

```
from .models import ResUsers, ResCompany
admin.site.register(ResUsers)
admin.site.register(ResCompany)
```

also ResUsers is declared before ResCompany in `models.py`

Comment: While defining `ForeignKey` write the model name `ResUsers` without  '  '  and do migrate again and check.

Comment: I did, it says : name 'ResUsers' is not defined. same error for "res_ users ",

Comment: Have you declared `ResUsers ` before `ResCompany` ? If not then declare `ResUsers `  before `ResCompany`  . and if `ResUsers `   is in different app the first import it, then do makemigrations and migrate

Comment: not working, even in 0001_initial.py can't find the ForeignKey, the same app